# SQL Server, T-SQL: weird behavior on "multiple value INSERT INTO statement" + sql_variant type column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert, union-all

Writing a script to experiment with `sql_variant` data type and `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` function (to recover data information from a `sql_variant` column) on SQL Server I discover, accidentally, what I consider an unexpected behavior on a multiple value `INSERT INTO` statement.

The following script illustrates the behavior:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TblVariant AS TABLE (
         rowid int identity
        ,VariantValue sql_variant
        ,AsStringColumn varchar(max)
        ,AsStringTypeInfo varchar(max)
        ,AsStringValue varchar(max)
        ,Result varchar(max)
    )

    --Inserting multiple values with one INSERT INTO statement
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue)
    VALUES (convert(float        ,10.25))
          ,(convert(int          ,11.00))
          ,(convert(numeric(10,0),12.15))
          ,(convert(numeric(10,2),13.50))
          ,(convert(bigint       ,14.75))
          ,(null)

    UPDATE @TblVariant 
    SET AsStringColumn = convert(varchar(max),VariantValue)
          ,AsStringTypeInfo = 
                 'BaseType='  +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'BaseType')),'NULL')
               +';Precision=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Precision')),'NULL')
               +';Scale='     +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Scale')),'NULL')
               +';TotalBytes='+isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'TotalBytes')),'NULL')
               +';Collation=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Collation')),'NULL')
               +';MaxLength=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'MaxLength')),'NULL')

    SELECT *
    FROM @TblVariant

    DELETE @TblVariant

    -- Multiple insert statements 
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (convert(float, 10.25))
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (convert(int, 11.00))
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (convert(numeric(10, 0), 12.15))
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (convert(numeric(10, 2), 13.50))
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (convert(bigint, 14.75))
    INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES (NULL)

    UPDATE @TblVariant 
    SET AsStringColumn = convert(varchar(max),VariantValue)
          --Ojo a este comportamiento. Al 
          ,AsStringTypeInfo = 
                 'BaseType='  +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'BaseType')),'NULL')
               +';Precision=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Precision')),'NULL')
               +';Scale='     +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Scale')),'NULL')
               +';TotalBytes='+isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'TotalBytes')),'NULL')
               +';Collation=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'Collation')),'NULL')
               +';MaxLength=' +isnull(try_convert(varchar(max),SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(VariantValue,'MaxLength')),'NULL')

    SELECT *
    FROM @TblVariant
END
```

The script above uses a table variable `@TblVariant` with a `sql_variant` column named `VariantValue` to store some data, inserts some values into `@TblVariant` and then uses `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` to recover data type info from the column `VariantValue`.

The first scenario inserts the multiple values using **one** `INSERT INTO` statement, after data deletion from `@TblVariant`, the second scenario repeats the process using **multiple** `INSERT INTO` statements to repopulate `@TblVariant` with the same data

The result looks as follows

[image]

As we see, in both scenarios the values in `VariantValue` and `AsStringColumn` look equal for all rows, but the calculated column `AsStringTypeInfo` looks different on each scenario.

For the **one** `INSERT INTO` statement scenario, the results for almost all rows (except for the row with null on `VariantValue` column) are the same; whilst on the other hand for the **multiple** `INSERT INTO` statements scenario, the value calculated for `AsStringTypeInfo` look different for each row providing more accurate info for the value inserted / stored on the `VariantValue` column, for each row.

My question is: what is the difference between to perform **one** `INSERT INTO` statement to insert multiple row values and to perform **multiple** `INSERT INTO` statements to insert the same values, and why that difference affects the `SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY` function behavior ?

Comment: Values() is a table value constructor: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 . Each column of values() (since it is a table constructor) must be of the same single datatype. The first, multiple, values statement has multiple datatypes, the one with the highest precedence is float, the values outputs float which  is converted to variant when inserted into the table. In short values() performs a  “union all” of each row (from the execution plan, constant scan, <OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Union1009">..

Comment: You could cast/convert one of the values to sql_variant, then variant is of the highest precedence..INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue)  VALUES (convert(sql_variant, convert(float        ,10.25))) ,(convert(int,11.00)) ,(convert(numeric(10,0),12.15))….

Comment: Thanks for your comment @lptr . As far as I understand your explanation, and I read from documentation you post, when inserting through a Table Value Constructor Values() statement the values beyond the first row are "casted" to the type of highest [precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) in this case ´float´ causing column `VariantValue` for all rows in `@TblVariant` be stored as a `sql_variant(float)`. I think that is the answer, you can upgrade your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As answered by @lptr in comments:

`Values()` is a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16). Each column of `values()` (since it is a table constructor) must be of the same single datatype.

The first, multiple, values statement has multiple datatypes, so the one with the highest precedence is `float`. The `values` outputs `float` which is converted to `sql_variant` when inserted into the table. In short, `values()` performs a `union all` of each row (from the execution plan, `constant scan`, `<OutputList><ColumnReference Column="Union1009">`

You could cast/convert one of the values to `sql_variant`, then `sql_variant` is of the highest precedence

```
INSERT INTO @TblVariant (VariantValue) VALUES
(convert(sql_variant, convert(float ,10.25))),
(convert(int,11.00)),
(convert(numeric(10,0),12.15))
```